# PHP: Questions about => global $nameOfVariable

Tags: php, global

```
global $nameOfVariable;
```

I have that inside of two functions, and I want to share its value between those two functions.  They are in separate files.

So I have this...

```
function a() {
global $nameOfVariable;

}

function b() {
global $nameOfVariable;

 a();

}
```

Function a() does most of the heavy lifting, but I'd like to pass that variable to function b().  The problem is, I think b() is trying to reproduce all of a().

I've tried using a($nameOfVariable), hoping it would just get that variable, but the result is the same.

a() and b() are on separate files.  Should place them on the same file?

Comment: The nameOfVariable needs to be defined outside the functions at least once.

Comment: Thank you.  I will look into that.

Comment: Avoid globals wherever possible. If you need to reuse a value in another function, return it from the first one and make the second one take it as a parameter.

Comment: Please provide a little more descriptive code or comment. We have no idea what are you trying to achieve with that glob